# Error building Saiku 2.4 bi-platform-plugin

Tags: java, maven, pentaho, building, saiku

I'm trying to install Saiku into Pentaho biserver-ce 3.7. I'm following [this tutorial](https://interestingittips.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/complete-pentaho-installation-on-ubuntu-part-3/). As the links in the tutorial don't work anymore, I downloaded Saiku release 2.4 from [Github](https://github.com/OSBI/saiku/archive/2.4.tar.gz), unzipped it, and I'm running `./saiku build bi-platform-plugin` to build. However, it throws some error, and finally shows this:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:56 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-02T09:01:44-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/169M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project saiku-bi-platform-plugin: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.saiku:saiku-bi-platform-plugin:jar:2.4: Failed to collect dependencies at org.saiku:saiku-service:jar:2.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.saiku:saiku-service:jar:2.4: Could not transfer artifact org.saiku:saiku-service:pom:2.4 from/to pentaho-third-party (http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/third-party/): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/third-party/org/saiku/saiku-service/2.4/saiku-service-2.4.pom. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Has anyone succesfully built saiku 2.4 bi-platform-plugin? Or, more important, know how to install saiku into Pentaho biserver-ce 3.7?

Answer (score 0):

3.7 version of biserver get outdated, as far as some online tutorals. The error is that build script trying to download saiku artifacts from  http://repo.pentaho.org while saiku seems no more in this repository. As far as repo.pentaho.org is obsolete. Use in your build scripts url like:

```
http://nexus.pentaho.org/#welcome
```

But this will not help since saiku no more hosted in pentaho repository. But it is hosted here:

```
http://repo.meteorite.bi/#nexus-search;quick~saiku
```

Update your build script with repositroy from meteorite, this may help. Also update versions of saiku dependencies to match versions still kept today. 2.4 seems a bit old.

Comment: I'll try and post here the results. Sorry for the late answer. Thanks a lot